# Как правильно программно добавить кнопку в TableLayout и установить OnClick?

Tags: android

Есть `TableLayout` в который хочу динамически помимо полей добавлять кнопки. Есть отдельный `xml(table_row)` содержащий разметку добавляемую.

```
<TableRow xmlns:android=""
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView android:text=""
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_margin="1dip"


<TextView android:text=""
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_margin="1dip"
    />
<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dip"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/CallButton"
    android:text=""
    />
```

Где содержится два `TextView` и `Button`.

В коде добавляю.

```
public void addRow(String str1, String str2)
{
    TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    TableRow tr = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row, null);

    TextView tv = (TextView) tr.getChildAt(0);
    tv.setText(str1);

    tv = (TextView) tr.getChildAt(1);
    tv.setText(str2);




    tableLayout.addView(tr);


  /*Попутный вопрос: Почему это код надо добавлять после   tableLayout.addView?
 Если добавить перед то приложение вылетает с ошибкой.*/
    Button button = (Button)tr.getChildAt(2);
    button.setText("Call");


}
```

В  `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` вызываю:

```
addRow("string1","string2");

    buttonCall = (Button)findViewById(R.id.CallButton);
    buttonCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Должно получиться что-то такого вида:

```
string1|string2|Button
```

Надо при нажатии на кнопку получить текст который находится в `string1`.

Пытаюсь просто обработчик нажатия проверить но хинт появляется только на первой строке. Если добавлено несколько строк, то обработчики кнопки не отрабатывают(кроме первой кнопки). Т.е необходимо как-то создать обработчик `OnClick` для каждой динамически создаваемой кнопки. И помимо этого, как-то определить в какой строке была нажата кнопка, что бы получить текст из этой же строки.

Надеюсь понятно описал проблему.

Попробовал вот так: В  `public void addRow ()` добавляют обработчик

```
Button button = (Button)tr.getChildAt(2);
    button.setText("Call");

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            TableRow tr=(TableRow)v;
            TextView tv1= (TextView)tr.getChildAt(0);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),tv1.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    {}
```

И получаю ошибку:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.widget.TableRow

Но этот же код работает если обработчик установить на `TableRow`.

```
tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

**Почему?**

Comment: Насчет попутного вопроса - методом addView вы добавляете на экран кнопку, иначе вы обращаетесь к несуществующей кнопке и получаете npe.

Comment: Asgard, почему тогда TextView добавляется перед addView? Вот этого и не понял.

Comment: я сделал предположение, ведь ошибку вы не вложили в вопрос.
Скорее всего, текст вью добавляется в уже созданный TableRow, а сам TableRow добавляется в tableLayout.
Но это все догадки.

Comment: если вы уже создали разметку в xml, то правильно будет искать элементы по id, вы делаете лишние действия, да и кстати вам необходимо уточнить вопрос. к примеру как программно(или наоборот) добавить в TableLayout -> Button & TextView и повесить слушатель для них.

Comment: Вот в этом всё и дело. ID получаются одинаковые. Т.к добавляется всегда те элементы, которые были созданы в xml. Они добавляются, но OnClick срабатывает только на первой добавленной кнопке.